# MySQL Query to Get Single Item and Latest Associated Item

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables

```
table1: { id, name }
table2: { id, table1_id, time_added }
```

It is possible to get all items in table1 with only the last added related item in table 2 in a single query?

Comment: What do you mean by "the last added related item in table 2" ? Those two tables have nothing in common so we can't use UNION and I don't totally understand what you want to select from table 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  t2.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t2.table1_id = t1.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(time_added) as time_added, table1_id FROM Table2 Group by table1_id) t2a on 
    t2a.time_added = t2.time_added AND t2a.table1_id = t2.table1_id
```

Comment: The subquery returns the max time_added and a random table1_id, I'm not sure that's what you want to do. Plus, that wouldn't necessarily select all items in table 1 since it's an inner join, maybe you're looking for an outer join (but to be honest, I didn't quite understand what OP wanted to do). Edit: Actually, this would only select one row due to your second join, as only one row max can match the condition.

Comment: @Vincent Savard  @Kirk ... yeah I had the query a little messed up...but this works.. and no an outer join is not necessary.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I (once again) read the question incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks! Was having a really hard time wrapping my head around this. Glad that it works with a single query. =]

Answer (score 0):

SELECT table1.id, table1.name FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id GROUP BY table2.id ORDER BY time_added DESC;

That's your answer, let me know if you need clarification.

Comment: @ajacian81...OP wants the following "get all items in table1 with only the last added related item in table2".  Your query does not return anything from table2 and will return duplicates from table1.   This is just not right!

Comment: John: The assumption here is that the id on table1 and table2 are the same.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple to select those item which are added last in table2.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 AS tb1 WHERE tb1.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE2)
```

NOTE : In the above query the id of table1 and id of table2 must be AUTO INCREMENTED.

Try this above query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With this solution you don't need subqueries... *based on ajacian81*

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.* 
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 
    ON table1.id = table2.table1_id 
GROUP BY table1.id 
ORDER BY table2.time_added DESC;
```